# Was the mystery of Christ in Ephesians 3:3-6 actually not revealed in the scriptures?

Tags: prophecy

> <sup>**3**</sup> that is, the mystery made known to me by revelation, as I have already written briefly. <sup>**4**</sup> In reading this, then, you will be able to understand my insight into the mystery of Christ, <sup>**5**</sup> which was not made known to people in other generations as it has now been revealed by the Spirit to God’s holy apostles and prophets. <sup>**6**</sup> This mystery is that through the gospel the Gentiles are heirs together with Israel, members together of one body, and sharers together in the promise in Christ Jesus. (NIV)

Was it not made known to any OT prophet whatsoever?

Comment: Apparently it wasn't, but there were other things that the OT prophets weren't clued in on either.  They knew what they needed to know at the time of their existence.

Comment: DYK: το μυστηριον, "the mystery" (EPH 3:3-4) refers to esoteric (secret) insider information that requires one to join and to be initiated into a religious or quasi-religious organization; e.g., the Freemasons, a cult or, for that matter, a church denomination? (See. e.g., Strong, Thayer, and Mounce at G3466.)

Answer (score 2):

The OT prophets were surely knowing something about the mystery, but incomplete. Isaiah 56:5-7 & Zechariah 14:16-19 did prophesize the gentiles will become the people of the Lord. It was the outcome but didn't tell how. It was like a jigsaw puzzle, there were pieces everywhere in the OT, but nobody was capable to piece them together, until Paul.

So in Ephesians 3:3-6, Paul was saying he finally resolved the completeness of the mystery.

Answer (score 2):

Paul is referring to the inclusion of non-Jews in the religion, without conversion to Judaism or becoming Jewish. Not the fact of the Messiah itself; although various details of the Messiah such as his death and suffering were not clearly understood by most. They were understood by a few, but were not so clear. There are some teachings in the Jewish sources that talk about the Messianic age, but as the prophecies they too maybe vague and hidden.

John Eadie commentary states on [Eph 3:5](https://www.studylight.org/commentaries/eng/jec/ephesians-3.html#verse-5)

> The general sense of the verse is evident. The apostle does not seem to deny all knowledge of the mystery to the ancient world, but he only compares their knowledge of it, which at best was a species of perplexed clairvoyance, with the fuller revelation of its terms and contents given to modern apostles and prophets; or as Theodoret contrasts it-οὐ γὰρ τὰ πράγματα εἶδον, ἀλλὰ τοὺς περὶ τῶν πραγμάτων προέγραψαν λόγους. In Vetere Testamento Novum latet, et in Novo Vetus patet. The scholium in Matthiae—“that the men of old knew that the Gentiles should be called, but not that they should be fellow-heirs,” contains a distinction too acute and refined. The intimations in the Old Testament of the calling of the Gentiles are frequent, but not full; disclosing the fact, but keeping the method in shade. The apostle James refers to this in Act 15:14. But after the death of Christ, which, by its repeal of the ceremonial code, was the grand means of Judaeo-Gentile union, a church, without reference to race, was fully organized. The salvation of guilty men of all races became a distinctive feature of the gospel, and therefore the incorporation of non-Israel into the church, revealed to Peter and Paul by the Spirit, was more clearly understood from the results of daily experience and the fruits of missionary enterprise. Act 11:17-18; Act 15:7; Act 15:13.

Also, it is a human tendency to ignore some plain teachings under the traditional mindset. The Jews believed that the [gentiles are created just as fuel for hell fire](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/95403/are-countries-with-other-religions-doomed-for-hell/95475); and ironically, the new covenant gentiles believe the same thing about unbelievers. Thus, a hidden minor fact about the gentiles inclusion in the Messianic age, to be mystery, is not surprising.

Answer (score 1):

At least in Isaiah 56 it is said very clear:

> [Salvation for Foreigners](https://biblehub.com/isaiah/56-6.htm)
> …5I will give them, in My house and within My walls, a memorial and a name better than that of sons and daughters. I will give them an everlasting name that will not be cut off. 6**And the foreigners** who join themselves to the LORD to minister to Him, to love the name of the LORD, and to be His servants— all who keep the Sabbath without profaning it and who hold fast to My covenant— 7**I will bring them to My holy mountain and make them joyful in My house of prayer**. Their burnt offerings and sacrifices will be accepted on My altar, for My house will be called a house of prayer **for all the nations**.”…
> Berean Standard Bible

Comment: You might also mention [Zechariah 14:16–19](https://www.blueletterbible.org/nkjv/zec/14/16-19/s_925016), where the Gentile nations celebrate the Feast of Tabernacles and worship "the King, the LORD of hosts".

Answer (score 1):

Paul makes two distinct points in this passage:

1. That the mystery of God was revealed to him (Paul) by direct revelation and not by anyone's teaching.  He makes this same point in other places as well:

- Gal 1:12 - For I neither received it from man, nor was I taught it, but by a revelation of Jesus Christ.  See also 1 Cor 2:7-15 and 2 Cor 12:17

2. This mystery is, contrary to the very exclusiveness of the Jews, available to all people, including the Gentiles. "*through the gospel the Gentiles are heirs together with Israel, members together of one body, and sharers together in the promise in Christ Jesus.*"

The latter "mystery" was indeed made known in OT times in numerous places.  Indeed, the Old Testament contains many examples of foreigners becoming part of Israel, indicating that the Israelite Covenant was open to all and was never exclusive.  For example:

- Abraham’s own household must have consisted of perhaps 2000 people just to be able to raise an army of 318 men to liberate Lot, Gen 14:14.  Indeed, Abraham’s chief servant (from Damascus) was clearly a believer and very devout as shown in Gen 24.
- The unfortunate story in Gen 38 about Judah and Tamar shows that a foreigner became the mother of the tribe of Judah.
- When Jacob entered Egypt, his family numbered 75 people (Acts 7:14, Ex 1:5).  Some of these were not direct descendants of Abraham such as the wives of the 12 patriarchs, notably Joseph’s own wife.  215 years and four generations later at the exodus, Israel’s army had over 600,000 men, excluding women and children, (Ex 12:37, Num 1:46, etc) suggesting a total population of several million people, requiring many additions.  This included a significant mixed multitude (Ex 12:38) showing that Israel obviously consisted of many non-biological Jews had joined.  (Note that it is biologically impossible for Israelite numbers to have grown from 75 to several million biologically without many outside additions.)
- Moses married a Midianite (Ex 2:16-21) also known as a Cushite.  Miriam and Aaron were severely reprimanded and punished for displaying racism (Num 12:1, 2)
- Caleb, who represented and led the tribe of Judah was a Kennizite (Num 32:12).
- Rahab was a Canaanite (Josh 2:1, 2, Matt 1:5)
- Ruth was Moabite (Ruth 1:4 16, 17, Matt 1:5) – these last two make King David descended from foreigners (Ruth 4:13-16).
- Uriah was a Hittite (2 Sam 11:3)
- King David’s elite personal regiment consisted of Gittites, that is, Philistines (2 Sam 15:18-22, 1 Chron 18:17)
- Isa 56:6, 7 - And the **foreigners who join themselves to the LORD** to minister to Him, to love the name of the LORD, and to be His servants— all who keep the Sabbath without profaning it and who hold fast to My covenant—I will bring them to My holy mountain and make them joyful in My house of prayer.  Their burnt offerings and sacrifices will be accepted on My altar, for **My house will be called a house of prayer for all the nations**.”  See also V3.
- The Rechabites were Kenites (Jer 35:1-19)
- Many other foreigners lived in Israel (1 Chron 22:2, 17, 2 Chron 30:25)
- In Esther’s time “many of the people of the land became Jews” (Esther 8:17, 9:27)
- Even in NT times, many Jewish synagogues were attended by godly gentiles converted to Judaism (Acts 13:16, 26, 16:14, 17:17)
- Many Jewish proselytes came to worship in Jerusalem (John 20:20, Acts 2:9-11)
- Jesus quotes Isa 56:7, “My house shall be a house of prayer for all nations”, Mark 11:17.
- Further, biological Israelites could opt out of the covenant and be cut-off (Ex 30:33, 38, 31:14, Lev 7:20, 21, 25, 27).

Thus, Paul in Eph 3:3-6, is discussing his divine calling and divine instruction about the truth of Scripture revealed to him directly by God, and not as taught by men.  This was important because it meant Paul's teaching was "pure" and unadulterated by the perverted teachings of men.

Comment: You mention "latter" mystery. So there were multiple mysteries that Paul addressed?

Comment: @O.J. - the "latter" refers to the second point above only.  However, there is more than one mystery - there is the mystery of the gospel and the mystery of godliness, etc.

Comment: The NT names numerous mysteries such as the kingdom (Matt 13:11, Mark 4:11, Luke 8:10), of gentiles in Israel (Rom 11:25, 16:25, Eph 3:3-6), of God (1 Cor 2:1, 4:1, Col 2:2) of the resurrection (1 Cor 15:51), of spiritual things (1 Cor 2:7, 13:2, 14:2), of God's will (Eph 1:9), of the gospel (Eph 6:19), of lawlessness (2 Thess 2:7), of faith (1 Tim 3:9), of godliness (1 Tim 3:16), etc.